# Как запретить повторную отправку POST из формы?

Tags: wordpress, post, form

Создал обычную форму, храню ее в виде плагина, после обновления страницы она отправляется заново. Если бы это был обычный сайт (без движка), я бы мог сделать обычный редирект и тем самым очистить POST, но в WordPress, если я использую header() - ничего не происходит.

Как мне очистить POST, чтобы при обновлении страницы форма не срабатывала?

Моя форма:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Main form
*/
wp_reset_postdata();
# Подключаем скрипты и стили
function get_form(){
    $cat = $_POST['cat'];
    $cat2 = $_POST['cat2'];
    $tel = $_POST['tel'];
    if(isset($tel)) {
    if(strlen($tel) > 5) {
        $message = "Номер телефону: ".$tel."\nФорма навчання: ".$cat."\nСпецiальнiсть: ".$cat2."\nПередзвонiть менi!";
        mail("andersonfamily23@gmail.com", "Питання про вступ", $message);
    }
    else {
        $error[] = "* Неправильний формат номера телефону!";
    }
    }
    return '<div class="widget-item">
                    <div class="request-information">
                        <h4 class="widget-title">Отримати консультацію для вступу</h4>

                           <form action="/головна" method="post" class="request-info clearfix">
                            <div class="full-row">
                                <label for="cat">Форма навчання:</label>                
                                <div class="input-select">
                                    <select name="cat" id="cat" class="postform">
                                        <option value="Не обрана" />-- Вибір --
                                        <optgroup label="На базі 9 класів">
                                          <option />Денна форма навчання
                                        </optgroup>
                                        <optgroup label="На базі 11 класів">
                                          <option />Денна форма навчання
                                          <option />Заочна форма навчання
                                        </optgroup>
                                    </select>
                                </div> <!-- /.input-select -->  
                            </div> <!-- /.full-row -->

                            <div class="full-row">
                                <label for="cat2">Спеціальность:</label>                                               
                                <div class="input-select">
                                    <select name="cat2" id="cat2" class="postform">
                                        <option value="Не обрана" />-- Вибір --
                                        <option class="level-0" value="Облік і оподаткування" />Облік і оподаткування
                                        <option class="level-0" value="Інженерія програмного забезпечення" />Інженерія програмного забезпечення
                                        <option class="level-0" value="Підприємництво, торгівля та біржова діяльність" />Підприємництво, торгівля та біржова діяльність
                                        <option class="level-0" value="Технології легкої промисловості (швейне виробництво, виробництво та дизайн тканин і трикотажу)" />Технології легкої промисловості (швейне виробництво, виробництво та дизайн тканин і трикотажу)
                                        <option class="level-0" value="Фінанси, банківська справа та страхування" />Фінанси, банківська справа та страхування
                                    </select>
                                </div> <!-- /.input-select -->
                            </div> <!-- /.full-row -->

                            <div class="full-row">
                                <label for="tel">Номер телефону:</label>
                                <input required placeholder="+38 (___) __-__-___" type="text" id="tel" name="tel" />
                            </div> <!-- /.full-row -->
                            <div class="full-row">
                                <div class="submit_field">
                                    <span class="small-text pull-left">Відповідаємо на протязі двох робочих днів</span>
                                    <input class="mainBtn pull-right" type="submit" name="" value="Зробити запит" />
                                </div> <!-- /.submit-field -->
                            </div> <!-- /.full-row -->
                            </form>
                            <p style="color:red;">'.$error[0].'</p>
                    </div> <!-- /.request-information -->
                </div> <!-- /.widget-item --> ';
}

/* Шорткод [main_form] */
function insert_form($atts, $content=null){
$form = get_form();
return $form;
}
add_shortcode('main_form', 'insert_form');
function main_form(){
    print get_form();
}
?>
```

Comment: Как вариант используйте замену `header`, а именно `wp_redirect( '/example');`. https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_redirect

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action('init', 'my_plugin_function_redirect', 10);
function my_plugin_function_redirect() {
    if ( $_REQUEST['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' )
        header("Location: /");
}
```

Это как пример. Адаптируете функцию под себя.

Answer (score -1):

Погуглил и нашел популярное решение использования редиректов в плагинах (ибо функции wp_redirect() не работают):

Решение:
Сделать редирект с помощью JS.
echo "window.location.href = '".home_url()."';";

Comment: Это только у вас `wp_redirect()` и `header` не работают.

Comment: `header` и `wp_redirect()` могут не работать только в том случаи, если до их вызова какой-то контент уже вывелся. В противном случаи всё норм должно быть.

Comment: А как иначе? Плагин не может вызываться до контента

Comment: Плагины подключаются не только задолго до контента, но также раньше темы. Читайте про хуки WordPress, в вашем случае полезен init.